# How to limit length of Varchar between 2 and 100

Tags: mysql, spring

I have a table in MySQL database with a column named "name". I want that whenever any query comes to store name in this column, name's length should be >2 and <= 100.

And the name should start with alphabet only.

I don't want to place this check on Database Table. I want to place this check inside code.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "member")
public class Member implements Serializable{

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 9045098179799205444L;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  Long id;

  @Column(name = "name")
  String name;

  @Column(name = "email")
  String email;

}
```

Comment: “I don't want to place this check on Database Table” MySQL does not even support that

Comment: @RaymondNijland Of course MySQL does support that. You can use MySQL Triggers to perform a validation before the save.

Comment: No @jdickel this is where you are wrong.. MySQL parse CHECK in CREATE TABLE statements but **not** execute them its in the manual.. And like you said you can use a update and a insert trigger to simulate CHECK constraint in MySQL as a workaround

Comment: I never wrote about the CHECK Statement. I also never said that this is best practice. I Just said that it’s not impossible and thats true.

Answer (score 1):

```
Validate it before the persistence with javax.validation.constraints.Size;
    @Size(min = 2, max = 200, message 
          = "name field must be between 2and 200 characters")
    @Column(name = "name")
      String name;
```

Comment: This does not ensure that the first character is an alphabet character and the requirement was a length larger than 2 and less than or equal than 100. Your example is larger or equals than 2 and less or equal 200.

Comment: It throws javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [com.crossover.techtrial.model.Member] during persist time for groups

Comment: @jdickel, you are right it should be 3 & 100, covers only the length. Then Pattern annotation can be used to check
Android, hope it helps [example](https://thoughts-on-java.org/automatically-validate-entities-with-hibernate-validator/)

Answer (score 0):

There are Bean Validation annotations, like @Size and @Pattern for this purpose. You can annotate the desired field with them. [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/constraints/package-summary.html) is a list of those annotations.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want to place this check on Database Table. I want to place this check inside code.

**EDIT: This post is for people who don't want to use annotations and if you consider the Entity as '*Datatable*'. If you *want* to use annotations then use the regex below with the `@Pattern` [annotation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/constraints/Pattern.html)**

Well, if you don't want to store this in the database you either need to handle this in the service layer **above** the POJO or inside the Model *Member* Class.
Depending on your perspective towards POJO/DTO with or without business logic.

The check itself would be as simple as

```
public void setName(String name){
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[A-Za-z].{1,100}");
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(test);
  if(matcher.matches()){
    // save here
  }else{
    // handle error here (exception?!)
  }
}
```

This pattern checks, wheater the string starts with an alphabet character and has at least 2 more character after the alphabet character, up to a maximum of 99 characters after the first one.

Comment: What about using Size and Pattern?  I used Size as specified in one answer below. It throws Runtime Exception. I also put that exception in comment in  answer by Oleksandr Abasov.

Comment: Size and Pattern is also totally fine of you wanz to use annotations. It’s the cleaner way. The Exception might come from entries which are already in the Database?! Otherwise it might be a ForeignKey which does not fit?